# AngularJS ReferenceError: module is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner

This is the error message I am getting when I run Karma. it says it is happening at `controllerTest.js:13`

below are lines 1 to 4:

```
describe('forgotPasswordCtrl', function() {
    beforeEach(module('forgotPasswordApp'));
    var $controller;
    var returnMsg = 'Forgot password response message';
```

so I believe it is the `beforeEach` part. no idea why it is giving me this error

Comment: write some more code please.

Comment: Where are you defining the forgotPasswordApp module? Is the code defining it included in your karma-running browser? (ie. the files section of your configuration)

Comment: @sagar43 there is a lot of code, specify what is required for you to give an answer and i can try and provide

Comment: @doldt i am just running the tests in karma the actual code i am viewing is just in github that I can see

Comment: @RagingBull I'm not sure I follow. Are you trying to write tests for code that's only available in github? Make a local copy and include the files in the same environment that you're running your tests in.

Comment: @doldt sorry, I wasn't clear. but anyway my initial problem is solved. but thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the order of files loaded into the test browser environment might be wrong. Make sure you include the `module files first` and `then your test scripts`.